proplem with redux not re render the component when it be inside the "OnClick" event
My english is not very good sorry
btw i have using ract+redux
react code:
import gsap from "gsap";
import { useGSAP } from "@gsap/react";
import githubLogo from "../assets/github.png";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import store from "../assets/Store/store";
export default function NavBar() {
  const x = useSelector((state) => state.layout)
  console.log(x)
  useGSAP(() =>
    gsap.from(".nav-bar-item", {
      y: -100,
      stagger: {
        amount: 0.5,
        grid: [1, 1],
        from: "center",
      },
    })
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const main = () => {
    dispatch({type:"Main"})
  }
  const blog = () => {
    dispatch({type: "Blog"})
  }
  const about = () => {
    dispatch({type: "About"})
  }
  return (
    <section className="nav-bar flex justify-between p-3">
      <div className="h-fit">
        <h1 className="nav-bar-item text-yellow-600 text-5xl font-bold">N0</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-x-6 text-xl nav-bar-layouts h-fit p-3">
        <button
          className="nav-bar-item relative"
          onClick={main()}
        >
          Main
        </button>
        <button
          className="nav-bar-item relative"
          onClick={
            about()
        }
        >
          About
        </button>
        <button
          className="nav-bar-item relative"
          onClick={
            blog()
          }
        >
          Blog
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="h-fit">
        <a href="https://github.com/nfrx1" target="blank">
          <img
            src={githubLogo}
            className="nav-bar-item bg-white rounded-full border-zinc-950 w-16 h-16"
            alt="github"
          ></img>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}


import { createStore } from "redux";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type == 'Blog'){
        return {layout: "Blog"}
    }
    else if (action.type == 'About'){
        return {layout: "About"}
    }
    return {layout: "Main"}
}

const store = createStore(reducer)
export default store

}`
const store = createStore(reducer)
export default store
`
when i use dispatch out the OnClick event it worked and re render but when i use it in "OnClick" event it change the layout but not re render the component
i try to use useSelector and react toolkit

You are immediately invoking the callbacks instead of passing a reference to the callback to the onClick prop. Voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo."

Seemingly you write onClick wrong.
Try this: onClick={main} or
onClick={()=>main()}
